# Remove redundant sentences in a list with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove redundant sentences in a Python list. One sentence can be comprised in another, I'd like to keep the longest one.

E.g

```
    my_list = ['Her name is Laura and she\'s from Texas','October','He owns a 
    dog and a cat', 'Her name is Laura', 'He owns a dog', 'Marie will turn 
    eighteen in October']
```

After processing:

```
    my_list = ['Her name is Laura and she\'s from Texas','He owns a 
    dog and a cat', 'Marie will turn eighteen in October']
```

Comment: Please provide code that you have already attempted

Comment: Would a simple string compare really solve your Problem? What, if there are the sentences "He owns a cat", "He owns a dog", "He owns a cat and a dog"? If you can not analyze the Content, your result would be strange, I think

Answer (score 3):

A (slightly better than) quadratic solution, check if the next smallest entry is a substring in the subsequent bigger strings.

```
my_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: -len(x)) # sort in descending order of length

indices_to_delete = [] 
for i, x in enumerate(my_list[:]):
    for j, y in enumerate(my_list[:][i:]):
        if x in y:
            indices_to_delete.append(i)
            break

my_list = [x for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if i not in indices_to_delete]
```

One pitfall with this is approach is it sorts your data. Don't use it if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: It is a simple solution, that's true. But I'm afraid, it could be a little more complex. If, f.e. there are all sentences: "He owns a cat", "He owns a dog", "He owns a cat and a dog", you wouldn't eliminate "He owns a dog". I think, it would be nessesary to analyze the Content. And for this python might be the wrong tool, maybe it could be easier to find a way in Prolog or something like that.

Comment: @am2 OP has given no evidence in his question to show that he'd need to handle a case like that, or am I missing something?

Comment: I know, thats why I marked the answer as useful. But the Problem still exists. You could try to use regular expressions or anything else. But f.e. for me "october" and ".. in october" is not redundant, only the text sounds similar. That's not your Problem, but the prob of the OP. "ANDY is illegal", "SANDY is ill" makes "SANDY  is illegal"?

Comment: @am2 Well, if such a case arises then there's no simple way to solve that, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

This method counts up how many times each string is a substring of every other string in the list and eliminates any that are substrings of more than one.

```
my_list = [
    'Her name is Laura and she\'s from Texas', 'October',
    'He owns a dog and a cat', 'Her name is Laura', 'He owns a dog',
    'Marie will turn eighteen in October'
]

redundant_counts = [
    len([sent for other_sent in my_list if sent in other_sent]) for sent in my_list
]

my_list = [
    sent for count, sent in zip(redundant_counts, my_list) if count == 1
]
```